# Combining a few " find "commands in linux

Tags: linux, stream, command, pipe

```
find /home/imk-prac/ \( -type f -size -13c -name '*\?plik\?*' \) -o\( -type d -name '\[Kolo1\]*' \)2> /dev/nul;
```

This command counts normal files which has less than 13 symbols and contains a sequence of symbols ?plik?.
I want to add looking for files which were modified less than 30 days and I wrote this command:

```
find /home/imk-prac/ -type f -mtime -30 -exec ls -l {} \; > /dev/null
```

I don't know how to combine this two commands in to one. 
I wanted to add  looking for files with specified quantity of symbols and I found this command:

```
grep -Po '(^|\s)\S{64}(\s|$)' file
```

But there is the same problem or even worse, because of grep command.
Thanks for your time and I hope you will help me to figure it out ;)

Comment: Just use another `-o` to add each set of conditions.

Comment: BTW, you need a space between `-o` and `\(`

Comment: or if appropriate, use `-a` to indicate a logical AND condition your `find` options. Good luck.

Comment: I did : 
 find /home/imk-prac/ \( -type f -size -13c -name '*\?plik\?*' \) -o \( -type d -name '\[Kolo1\]*' \) -o\( -type f -mtime -30 -exec ls -l {} \; 2> /dev/null

Comment: it compiles, but not looking for - I have changed 30 on 300000 and doesn't seem to work - I added only a time